# AWS RDS can do column level encryption out of the box?

Tags: mysql, security, encryption, amazon-rds

We had an on premise Mysql server where we wanted to move to cloud. The obvious choice is RDS instance of mysql. 
At present we are using Database level encryption applied to few of our sensitive data in table coulmns. 
This we did using AESEncrypt and Decrypt. 
Does AWS has any out of the box feature to apply encryption while writing to table and decrypt them when read with out additional effort of programming?

Comment: Amazon RDS uses a standard deployment of MySQL. Thus, anything you can do in MySQL can be done in Amazon RDS for MySQL. There are no database-level differences just because it is running on RDS.

Comment: Yes I know, but I am interested if any AWS service provides data encryption out of the box for encryption data without handking it either from code or database side.

Comment: Only what is here: [Encrypting Amazon RDS Resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.Encryption.html)